# The setup routines for the < DRIVERNAME > could not be found. Please reinstall the driver

Tags: installation, odbc, registry, driver

I am using Windows 7 64 bit. I want to create a ODBC connection. I do the following:

1. Open ODBC console for 32 bit
2. Under the tab USER-DSN, I click "Add"
3. I choose the driver "SQL Anywhere 12"
4. I click finish

I now get this error:

"The setup routines for the < DRIVERNAME > could not be found. Please reinstall the driver.
Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed - Component not found in the registry"

I follow the solution found here: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4828

Unfortunately this does not work for me. I always get the same error. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Under `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI/SQL Anywhere 12"`

The Strings "Driver" and "Setup" where missing. I added the path to the 32-bit ODBC drivers. Now everything works again.